# Confusion regarding the transformation law under diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation

While revisiting the transformation laws - under a diffeomorphism - of the 
partial derivative of a vector field I got confused by the following result. So, for a vector field 
$A$ the usual transformation law is given by,

$$
A^{\alpha'}_{,\beta'}=\partial_{\beta'} A^{\alpha'}= \frac{\partial x^
{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\beta'}} 
A^\alpha_{,\beta} + \frac{\partial^2 x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}\partial 
x^{\beta}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\beta'}} A^\alpha~.
$$

However, for the last term on the RHS, using the properties of the partial 
derivatives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}\partial x^{\beta}} \frac
{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\beta'}} A^\alpha  & = \frac{\partial}{\partial 
x^\beta}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right) \frac{\partial x^
{\beta}}{\partial x^{\beta'}} A^\alpha \\
      & =\frac{\partial}{\partial 
x^{\beta'}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right) A^\alpha \\
      & = \frac{\partial}{\partial 
x^\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\beta'}}\right) A^\alpha \\
      & = \frac{\partial \delta^{\alpha'}_{\beta'}}{\partial
x^\alpha} A^\alpha =0~,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\delta^{\alpha'}_{\beta'}$ is the Kronecker delta and in the last equality it was used the fact that its derivative is zero.

Now, I know that this is wrong but I don't know where, could somebody help me find the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$ wrt. the unprimed coordinate system and derivatives 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime\beta}}~=~\frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial x^{\prime \beta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\gamma}}   $$ 
wrt. the primed coordinate system do not necessarily commute 
$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime\beta}}\right]~=~\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}},\frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial x^{\prime \beta}}\right]\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\gamma}},$$
since the Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial x^{\prime \beta}}$ may be non-constant.

Comment: I  think your completely correct but rather laconic answer should be a bit more verbose for clarification.

Comment: I updated the answer.